# Symfony not overriding bundle view

Tags: php, symfony, templates, overriding, sylius

I have been following the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) intending to override the Sylius Web Bundle layout.html.twig using inheritance.

The bundle file is at

```
/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig
```

I've placed a new file at

```
/src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig
```

I have also updated the file at:

```
/src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php
```

to inherit the relevant bundle

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'SyliusWebBundle';
    }
}
```

But the page stays the same. If I remove the original layout.html.twig, Symfony says there it cannot find the file. It never attempts to find my new file.

Does this configuration look correct? Is there a common misconfiguration which could be preventing this? Stepping through the debugger I can see that the getParent() function is being hit, but is there any other way I could debug this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely it is just cache.
The code you provided is correct, and it works for me it the exact same config.
so

`> php app/console cache:clear`

should be all that is needed

One other silly thing that it could be .. did you added your appbundle to appKernel.php ??

Comment: The problem was indeed the cache. I thought this wouldnt be the problem as I was using app_dev.php so the cache would not come into play.

Comment: @JackalopeZero some things are also cached when running with app_dev. Those are mostly things that needs to be parsed to php or needs to traverse/inspect a lot of files. eg. new configuration files, new translation files, new files overriding existing files. The full list should be in docs, but I didn't really searched for it.

Comment: I have the same problem above  i tried clearing  the cache folder manually but still the same issue 
"Bundle "AppBundle" extends bundle "SyliusWebBundle", which is not registered."

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the template at:

app/Resources/SyliusWebBundle/views/layout.html.twig